# Correct way to queue items for a worker goroutine?

Tags: go, race-condition, channel

I am writing an app that allows users to upload files and queue them for processing. My approach to this is to create a goroutine for processing uploaded files and to use a channel to signal that a new file is ready for processing.

Basically, the processing goroutine does this:

```
for {
    while itemForProcessing() {
        processNextItem()
    }
    select {
    case <-signalChan:
    case <-stopChan:
        return
    }
}
```

The code for signaling that a new item is ready for processing looks something like this:

```
select {
case signalChan <- true:
default:
}
```

Note that this is a non-blocking send on the channel.

There are three possible scenarios:

- the processing goroutine is in the `select{}` block — the first case runs and the next item is processed
- the processing goroutine is executing `processNextItem()` — the next item will be processed once `processNextItem()` returns since the loop condition will be `true`
- the processing goroutine has exited the loop *but has not yet entered the `select{}` block*

The last scenario will result in a problem. The non-blocking send will not send anything on the channel and the goroutine will wait in the `select{}` block until something else happens.

How can I avoid this problem? I cannot use a blocking send because the processing goroutine may be running `processNextItem()`, which would cause the send to block for an extremely long period of time.

Comment: Here channel works as an updatable flag - signaling there’s something what app can read. I guess there’s a possibility to simplify things - just pass new objects to treat via the channel. This solves several problems: easy parallelism, race condition protection, simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid a lost signal, use a channel with capacity 1.